# Logging out not working - Asp.net core identity server

Tags: c#, asp.net, identityserver4

I have a application where i have used identity server for authentication. I have some issue over there. Whenever i tried to log out from the system the system doesn't log out. It redirects to home page even if i have logged out. This is how i have configured my startup class

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
    })
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Name = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        options.LogoutPath = "/Home/Logout";
    })
    .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
    {
        options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";

        options.Authority = builder.Environment.IsDevelopment() ? appSetting.Development.IdentityServerUrl : appSetting.Production.IdentityServerUrl;
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

        options.ClientId = "technosys-inv-ui";
        options.ClientSecret = "technosys-inv-secret";
        options.ResponseType = "code id_token";

        options.SaveTokens = true;
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

        options.Scope.Add("technosys-inv-api");
        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("website", "website");
    });

    builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;
    });
```

And this is my log out action

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task Logout()
    {
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            RedirectUri = "/"
        });
    }
```

This is how i have configure client in identity server project.

```
public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        AppSettings appSettings = configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").Get<AppSettings>();
        AppSetting appSetting = null;
        if (appSettings.Environment == "Development")
            appSetting = appSettings.Development;
        else
            appSetting = appSettings.Production;

        return new[]
        {
            // client credentials flow client
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "technosys-inv-ui",
                ClientName = "Technosys Inventory UI",
                RedirectUris = { appSetting.AdminClientUrl + "signin-oidc" },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { appSetting.AdminClientUrl },
                FrontChannelLogoutUri = appSetting.AdminClientUrl + "signout-oidc",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Hybrid,
                ClientSecrets = { new Secret("technosys-inv-secret".ToSha256()) },
                AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                AllowedScopes = { "technosys-inv-api", "openid","profile" },
                RequireConsent = false,
            }
        };
    }
```

This is my client application
[image]

If i click the logout button it redirects to identity server pages and prompt, you are logged out.
[image]

But if i click here tag it redirect to client home page instead it should show the login page after logout.

**NOTE: Log out work on local but doesnot work on production**

Any help would be appreciated thanks ...!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I typically use this method to trigger the logout:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task Logout()
{
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

    //Important, this method should never return anything.
}
```

Also, I would suggest that you should be consistent with the naming of the authentication handlers, and don't mix your own strings and the default names.

```
options.SignInScheme = "Cookies"; vs options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
```

and

```
AddOpenIdConnect("oidc" vs
AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
```

It's easy to make a bug where you accidentally rename the string values. Consistency is the key here.

Also, options.LogoutPath = "/Home/Logout"; needs to match the exact URL to your logout page.

I would also set options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Unspecified; to  strict if possible.

Comment: After changing according to your comment now it is asking if you really wanna logout but again it redirects to home page

Comment: I think that is a Client setting in IdentityServer that controls that. Does it otherwise log you as as you expect?

Comment: I have updated my question can you please look into it

Comment: What is the actual problem right now? In the client you have "  PostLogoutRedirectUris = { appSetting.AdminClientUrl }," , that will redirect to the client homepage after logout?

Comment: yes it redicted to client home page. Even after removing that line, it redirects to home page

Comment: So, what what is the problem? what do you want to happen instead?

Comment: redirect to login page after log out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250314/discussion-between-nishan-dhungana-and-tore-nestenius).

Comment: I guess you need to set in the client, the PostLogoutRedirectUris = { appSetting.AdminClientUrl + "signout-callback-oidc" }, or something similar, so that IDentityServer can redirect you back to the openid-connect handler in your client. see https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/reference/models/client/

Comment: I think you should set PostLogoutRedirectUris =  appSetting.AdminClientUrl + "/signout-callback-oidc",   so that IdentityServer can redirect back to the openidconnect handler , that then will redirect you to "/"

Comment: Does this work? or do you still have problems?

Answer (score 2):

Using middleware, you can detect the unauthenticated user and issue a challenge to redirect to login page.

You may also need to detect whether there is a signout in progress, I don't have the code for that off the top of my head but it should be added into the `if` condition if it is relevant for your situation.

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
         HttpContext.Authentication.ChallengeAsync( .... );// issue challenge here
    }

    await next(context);
});
```